# How do i implement loging framework to place critical logs on server where error was on client

Tags: c#, logging, client, nlog

I have a client server architecture. i want to push my log to predefined folder on server when ever there is a critical error occurred. i am currently using nLog for logging. is there a way to do same in nLog (note: i am not interested in emailing the log as there may not be a internet connectivity to my client )

Comment: What you categorize as client errors? Do you have HMTL5 application targetting to modern browsers?

Answer (score 0):

This are a bit contradicting specs: If there is a 'critical error' there is also a hign probability that the connection to the server is lost. So it is no longer possible to send information about the *critical event* to the server.

I'd suggest to **not reinvent the wheel**

You may configure nLog to log to the *local* windows event log.
This log is accessible from the server.